# Find duplicates in NSArray

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsarray

Say you have an `NSArray` with duplicates `@[1,2,3,1,1,2,4,5,6]`;

Find all the duplicates; this can be in pseudocode. This is more of a algorithm question than a Foundation framework (without the use of `NSSet`) question.

Comment: Have a look at NSCountedSet. You could create one of those from your array, then loop through and see which ones have a count greater than 1.

Comment: I never knew NSArray could store Integer values directly. :O

Answer (score 22):

as @Lithu described, use `NSCountedSet` , see the below code.

```
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@(1),@(1),@(2), @(1),nil];
NSCountedSet *cs = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:arr];
NSLog(@"object count greater than 1 are");
for(NSNumber *num in cs)
{
    if([cs countForObject:num]>1)
    NSLog(@"%@",num);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Use an   `NSCountedSet`
 and only print the elements that returns a number>1 for `countForObject:` method

Refer [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information